# How to convert scikit image to byte stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

How can I convert a `scikit` image read from file:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread(f)
```

to a byte stream like the `image_binary` in the following:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("group1.jpeg")
stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()
```

I saw in the following [link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/data_types.html#working-with-opencv) how to convert to `cv2` images, but not to byte streams.

Answer (score -3):

This is what I ended up using:

```
from PIL import image
from skimage import io

img = io.imread(f)
image = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
# ...
```